# How to set corresponding GCC flags and environment variables in Eclipse CDT

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu-11.10, festival

Hi i have been trying to make a c++ program of mine to work on Linux GCC
I have used a Text to speech lib called Festival 2.1

```
<code>
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<festival/festival.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int heap_size=210000;
    int load_init_files=1;
    festival_initialize(load_init_files,heap_size);
    festival_say_text("Hi dude, how are you ?");
    festival_wait_for_spooler();
    return 0;
}
</code>
```

This is my program.
g++ test.cpp -l Festival -I/usr/include/festival  -I/usr/lib/speech_tools/include -leststring -lestools -lestbase
Using this i am able to compile successfully and exec could be created.

But, how do i set env variables etc in Eclipse CDT(ubuntu 11.10) to work using this code ..
Now i am getting the error

/home/gp/WORKSPACE-CDT/LBOT/Debug/../src/test.cpp:21: undefined reference to `festival_initialize(int, int)'
/home/gp/WORKSPACE-CDT/LBOT/Debug/../src/test.cpp:22: undefined reference to`EST_String::EST_String(char const*)'
/home/gp/WORKSPACE-CDT/LBOT/Debug/../src/test.cpp:22: undefined reference to `festival_say_text(EST_String const&)'
/home/gp/WORKSPACE-CDT/LBOT/Debug/../src/test.cpp:23: undefined reference to`festival_wait_for_spooler()'
./src/test.o: In function `EST_Chunk::operator--()':
/usr/include/speech_tools/EST_Chunk.h:140: undefined reference to`EST_Chunk::~EST_Chunk()'
/usr/include/speech_tools/EST_Chunk.h:140: undefined reference to `EST_Chunk::operator delete(void*)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [LBOT] Error 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found the solution to this.
So if anyone gets the same problem running Festival tts, it can help :)
basically the environment flags and variables can be set in eclipse through project properties and changing the toolchain settings
STEPS:
UBUNTU 11.10

GCC 4.x pre-installed

Elipse CDT was installed using terminal command

pthreads configured in eclipse using: project->preferences->c/c++ build/settings->GCC linker-> library vars add "pthreads"

Festival installed using: sudo apt-get install festival

Festival dev installed using: sudo apt-get install festival-dev festvox-don build-essential g++

Unresolved inclusion error: goto eclipse, project->preferences->c/c++ build/settings and add festival,speech_tools path to c,c++,linker directories

```
#include<stdio.h>

#include<festival.h>

int main(int argc,char **argv)

{

int heap_size=210000;

int load_init_files=1;

festival_initialize(load_init_files,heap_size);

festival_say_text("it is lunch time");

festival_wait_for_spooler();

return 0;

}
```

TERMINAL

```
sudo g++ main.cpp -l Festival -I/usr/include/festival  -I/usr/lib/speech_tools/include -l eststring -l estools -l estbase -o nat.out
```

ECLIPSE

project->preferences->c/c++ build/settings->GCC linker-> library vars add 'Festival'

project->preferences->c/c++ build/settings->GCC linker-> library vars add 'eststring'

project->preferences->c/c++ build/settings->GCC linker-> library vars add 'estools'

project->preferences->c/c++ build/settings->GCC linker-> library vars add 'estbase'